# « Armance était supposée écrire à son amie [...] une longue lettre » ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, passif

**Le texte**

> <sub>[...] - "Une **supposition** de lettre est atroce, s'écria le
>   chevalier. Aimez-vous votre neveu avec une affection assez vive pour
>   que la fin puisse justifier le moyen?" [...]</sub>
>
> <sub>Enfin après quinze jours de patience, **le commandeur eut l'idée de
>   composer une lettre d'Armance à Méry de Tersan, son amie intime.** [...]</sub>
>
> <sub>Le chevalier [...] enfin obtint un modèle de lettre point assez
>   emphatique et allemand, mais enfin à peu près raisonnable. Le modèle
>   de lettre arrêté après une discussion si orageuse, fut présenté par le
>   commandeur à son calqueur d'autographes qui, croyant qu'il ne
>   s'agissait que de propos galants, n'opposa que la difficulté
>   nécessaire pour se faire bien payer, et imita à s'y tromper l'écriture
>   de Mlle de Zohiloff. **Armance était supposée écrire à son amie Méry
>   de Tersan une longue lettre sur son prochain mariage avec Octave.** ⇐</sub>
>
> <sub>[...] En arrivant à Andilly il sauta de son cheval, courut au
>   jardin et en cachant sa lettre sous quelques feuilles dans le coin de
>   la caisse d'oranger, il en trouva une d'Armance.</sub>
>
> [ [Henri Beyle (*Stendhal*)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stendhal), *Armance, Quelques scènes d'un salon de
>   Paris en 1827*, [Chapitre XXIX](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Armance/Chapitre_XXIX), Paris, 1827 ]

En premier lieu le chevalier s'objecte à l'idée du commandeur de concevoir une fausse lettre. Le commandeur détermine en quoi cette lettre consistera; une lettre entre Armance et son amie Méry. Le commandeur fait rédiger la fausse lettre par son calqueur. À ce moment on sait quel moyen (une fausse lettre) va utiliser le commandeur pour ruiner le mariage de son neveu avec Armance; on sait de qui et pour qui la fausse lettre provient/est destinée. On dit qu'Armance était *censée/supposée* écrire une lettre à son amie. Mais Armance ne devait pas envoyer quoi que ce soit à ce que je sache (je n'ai pas lu l’œuvre), même si on peut imaginer que des amies s'écrivent généralement; c'est le commandeur qui est entièrement responsable de l'imposture. D'autre part, il n'y a plus de doute non plus sur le fait qu'Armance envoie une lettre à son amie maintenant, suite à cette mise en scène. Pourtant, on a le verbe employé à la voix passive avec Armance comme sujet et  il y a accord. Est-ce bien le sens usuel et contemporain de *supposer* que Stendhal utilise ici quand il dit d'Armance qu'elle **était supposée écrire** une lettre à son amie, alors que le contexte ne semble pas l'autoriser, à mon avis ?

---

Voici un extrait pertinent du *TLFi*, à *supposer* (voir aussi l'adjectif [*supposé*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/suppos%C3%A9), par ex. *testament supposé*, fabriqué dans un but frauduleux etc.) :

> **A.** − Empl. trans.
>  [...]
>   **3.** Poser comme vrai quelque chose de faux, avec intention de tromper.
>   **a)** *Vieilli*. Produire, alléguer pour vrai quelque chose de faux; prétendre.
>  *Je suis arrivée un peu avant l'heure du dîner à
>   Loewenstein; on a été surpris de me voir; mais j'ai supposé une
>   affaire qui avait avancé un voyage que je devais faire* (Sénac de
>   Meilhan, Émigré, 1797, p. 1651). *Deux mois après le mariage, j'irai
>   voyager avec mon mari, et il nous sera facile de supposer que mon fils
>   est né à une époque convenable* (Stendhal, Rouge et Noir, 1830, p.
>   437).
>  − **Supposer qqc. à qqn.** Attribuer faussement quelque
>   chose à quelqu'un. (Dict. xix<sup>e</sup> et xx<sup>e</sup> s.). 
>   **b)** Substituer quelque chose à autre chose; mettre une chose à la place d'une autre en la donnant pour authentique. [...]
>   *Il ne soupçonnait point les Barricini de meurtre (...) mais il les accusait d'avoir supposé la lettre du bandit Agostini; et cette lettre
>   (...) avait causé la mort de son père* (Mérimée, *Colomba*, 1840, p.
>   82).
>  − *Supposer **un enfant***. ,, Vouloir le faire passer, le
>   faire reconnaître pour fils ou fille de ceux dont il n'est pas né``
>   (*Ac. 1798-1935*). *On supposa un enfant pour frustrer les héritiers
>   collatéraux* (*Ac.1798-1935*). [...]
>   **B.** − Empl. pronom.
>   1. *passif*. Être supposé. *La culpabilité ne se suppose pas, elle se prouve. En fait, l'inégalité des facultés existe; en droit, elle n'est
>   point admise, elle ne compte pour rien, elle ne se suppose pas*
>   (**Proudhon**, *Propriété*, 1840, p. 278). 
>   [...]

Avec l'emploi pronominal dans *Proudhon*, au passif, on ne traite pas du *faux* mais plutôt d'un concept proche de l'*allégation*, certainement quelque chose qui n'est aucunement étayé. Si on reprend la citation de *Stendhal* à la voix active avec le sujet réel (ceux qui conspirent, au premier chef le commandeur), en agençant les compléments selon la tournure *supposer qqc. à qqn.*, tel que présenté au sens A.3.a, on obtient :

> On avait supposé à Armance (d')écrire à son amie Méry de Tersan une longue
>   lettre sur son prochain mariage avec Octave.

Est-ce que Stendhal a réussi à camoufler ceci dans cela.

---

*Questions* (sur l'[extrait d'*Armance* de Stendhal](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Armance/Chapitre_XXIX) marqué avec ⇐)

- S'agit-il bien du sens **A.3 a** *supposer qqc. à qqn.* dont il est question (sinon comment réconcilie-t-on le sens usuel avec le contexte du chapitre) ? Comment *Armance* peut-elle être le sujet ici alors qu'elle n'est aucunement impliquée dans l'action (un mot sur la grammaire<sup>1</sup>) ?

---

<sub>1. Dans *Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, ed. *Duculot*) on note au §905 que quand *supposer* signifie *impliquer*, il emprunte sa construction (avec *de*; *supposer* étant généralement un verbe qui n'utilise pas la préposition avant l'infinitif). Au §902 6°, on aborde directement la citation de *Stendhal*. On se questionne sur la réalité du sujet. On dit que selon les propos de *Sandfeld*, ça correspond à une construction active avec une proposition infinitive comme complément direct, sauf dans le cas de *être censé*, figé au passif. Puis on note que l'on fait l'accord avec le pronom personnel renvoyant au sujet apparent. Au §772 f), on aborde les verbes au passif suivi d'un infinitif; on a une catégorie pour les verbes d'opinion souvent employés au passif avec un attribut, mais qui peuvent aussi prendre l'infinitif, dont *supposer* (« *Dans cette théorie, la vitesse est supposée constante, être constante* », *Grand dictionnaire encyclopédique Larousse*); mais c'est dans le même sens que l'exemple de *Proudhon*; et non pas dans le sens de la supercherie. Une sous-question est peut-être depuis quand en France on utiliserait « être supposé » pour dire « être censé » dans le sens de « devoir en principe ». Si on supposait que c'est ce sens là (être supposé = être censé = devoir) qui est utilisé dans la citation, on dit alors que l'influence de l'anglais sur l'emploi est déjà réalisé en 1827. Le *DHLF/Rey* note mais n'établit pas la date à partir de laquelle l'influence de l'anglais se fait sentir dans l'emploi passif de *supposer* pour signifier *être censé*.</sub>

Comment: Je te prie de m'excuser, je vais mettre une version abrégée pour ne pas faire d'autres victimes. Effectivement, sur le court passage que tu as cité et que j'avais lu sur ton lien, je trouve le style assez indigeste et je peine à suivre son récit, mais c'est probablement une différence d'époque. Je pense aussi que c'est ce qui a causé notre incompréhension de « supposer » à la base.

Comment: Si ça peut aider à répondre, le résumé du contexte cité, trouvé sur [Studyrama](http://www.studyrama.com/reussir-ses-etudes/fiches-de-lecture/armance-de-stendhal-41220) : « Le commandeur [...], n’ayant jamais accepté le mariage, écrit une fausse lettre d’Armance à son amie intime et s’arrange pour qu’Octave l’intercepte. Dans cette lettre de quelques lignes, il fait dire à Armance qu'[...]. » Allez sur le site si connaître la suite ne vous dérange pas.

Answer (score 2):

A mon humble avis, la lettre est un faux destiné à tromper Octave. Ce faux  est censé avoir été écrit par Armance (mais ne l'est pas) et Armance y écrit qu'elle va se marier avec Octave (ce qui n'est a priori pas son intention).

La phrase précédente indique que l'écriture d'Armance (Mlle de Zohiloff) est contrefaite. "Supposer" pourrait vouloir dire que le commandeur a assez d'éléments pour deviner les pensées les plus intimes de la jeune femme (un projet de mariage), mais dans ce cas il est plus probable que l'auteur donne les détails de la lettre qui vient d'être écrite, à savoir son contenu: on veut faire accroire certaines pensées intimes d'Armance concernant son prochain mariage avec Octave. Uniquement sur base de ma lecture du paragraphe suivant, je présume que la lettre tombe dans les mains d'Octave et que cela va accélérer leur mariage.

Comment: @Amphiteóth La forme active c'est *"Armance est censé avoir écrit ce faux"*. Ce n'est pas ta question, si?

Comment: @Amphiteóth Bien que rigoureusement il s'agisse d'un participe passé, [_censé_ semble aujourd'hui considéré comme un adjectif](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cens%C3%A9#.C3.89tymologie). La forme active que propose Yohann me semble donc pertinente. Je pense que _supposer_ A.3.a n'est aujourd'hui utilisé que sous sa forme adjective comme dans [les exemples du wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/suppos%C3%A9#Adjectif). Je ne sais pas ce qu'il en était quand Stendahl écrivait il y a deux siècles. B.1 ne semble pas s'appliquer à ta question (emploi _pronominal_). M'égaré-je ?

Comment: @YohannV. Non non, je pose la question au présent de l'indicatif. Mais j'ai tendance à retenir [les orthographes d'avant 1990](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Grammaire_fran%C3%A7aise:La_postposition_du_sujet_%C2%AB_je_%C2%BB#Orthographe_traditionnelle). :) J'aime bien la post-position du « je » et quelques verbes ou locutions désuets voire archaïques. Désolé (pour mes manies et le hors-sujet).

Comment: (@YohannV. Sans ça, c'est difficile à prononcer. :) )

Comment: @Amphiteóth pour moi, Stendhal informe le lecteur (du roman) que le faux écrit par le commandeur vise à faire accroire (au lecteur de la fausse lettre, càd Octave) qu'Armance souhaite partager (avec sa meilleure amie) des nouvelles relatives à son projet de mariage avec Octave. Le commandeur s'arrange ensuite pour que cette fausse lettre tombe dans les mains d'Octave.

Answer (score 1):

Pour la sous-question :

> À cette heure là, il [ est supposé | doit | est censé] être en classe :

sont strictement équivalents au IIIe millénaire : l'enfant est *en principe* en classe, mais on ne *sait pas* s'il y est effectivement, il y a une *incertitude*.

C'est la réponse que fera un parent si on lui demande où est sont enfant, mais cette réponse laisse percer un doute : l'enfant peut ne pas être en classe pour un motif légitime (maître absent par exemple) ou non.

C'est la *même* réponse que fera son camarade avec qui il fait l'école buissonnière, et là, il a *tromperie*.

Stendhal fait une mise en scène : le fait de lever l’incertitude, de *révéler la manipulation* engage la tromperie ; sinon il y aurait *suspense*, dans notre exemple on peut se rendre à l'école et trouver l'élève... ou pas.

Ce qui est impliqué ne dépend pas du mot employé mais de sa mise en perspective.

Comment: L'exemple de la réponse était accepté plus d'un siècle avant le IIIe millénaire, si j'en crois ce que j'ai entendu des grands-parents. En revanche *aller* est 'exclus' comme mot de remplacement, car c'est un verbe qui reflète l'action, et non l'état (de la personne).